# Coordinate Representation of Multilinear Functions

Tags: differential-geometry, tensors, multilinear-algebra

I attempt to understand the coordinate representation of multilinear functions from *An Introduction to Manifolds* (Second Edition) by Loring Tu. Below I quote the relevant part of the book (page no. 31).

> **3.10 A Basis for $k$-Covectors**
>
> Let $e_1, \cdots, e_n$ be a basis for  areal vector space V, and $\alpha^1, \cdots, \alpha^n$ be the daul basis for $V^\vee$. Introduce the multi-index notation $$I = (i_1, \cdots, i_k)$$ and write $e_I$ for $(e_{i_1}, \cdots, e_{i_k})$ and $\alpha^I$ for $\alpha^{i_1} \wedge \cdots \wedge \alpha^{i_k}$.
>
> A $k$-linear function $f$ on $V$ is comepletely determined by its values on all $k$-tuples $(e_{i_1}, \cdots, e_{i_k})$. If $f$ is alternating, then it is completely determined by its values on $(e_{i_1}, \cdots, e_{i_k})$ with $1\leq i_1 < \cdots <i_k \leq n$; that is, it suffices to consider $e_I$ with $I$ in strictly ascending order.

**My Question**

I don't see how $f$ being alternative is completely determined by its values on $(e_{i_1}, \cdots, e_{i_k})$ with $1\leq i_1 < \cdots <i_k \leq n$. Can you please explain it to me, if possible by an example?

**My Attempts**

At first, I consider a multilinear function $f: V^k \to \mathbb{R}$ so that

\begin{eqnarray}
f(v_1, \cdots, v_k) &=& f\left(\sum_{i_1=1}^{n} v_{\color{red}{1}}^{i_1} \, e^{\color{red}{1}}_{i_1}, \cdots \cdots,  \sum_{i_k=1}^{n} v_{\color{red}{k}}^{i_k} \, e^{\color{red}{k}}_{i_k}\right) \\
&=& \sum_{i_1=1}^{n} \cdots \sum_{i_k=1}^{n} v_{\color{red}{1}}^{i_1} \cdots v_{\color{red}{k}}^{i_k} f\left(e^{\color{red}{1}}_{i_1}, \cdots \cdots,  e^{\color{red}{k}}_{i_k}\right),
\end{eqnarray}
and therefore is comepletely determined by its values on all $k$-tuples $(e_{i_1}, \cdots, e_{i_k})$.

But I can't derive the case for the alternating $k$-linear function from here.

Comment: Suppose that $e_{i_1},\dots,e_{i_k}$ is NOT in ascending order. Then since $f$ is alternating, you can just re-order them and the result will only change by $\pm 1$. For example, if $k=2$, and if $i<j$, then $f(e_j,e_i) = - f(e_i,e_j)$, so if you know it for $i<j$, then you also know it for $i>j$ by just switching the sign.

Comment: Consoder permutations of $(i_1, \cdots, i_k)$ and combine the result with the definition of alternating forms.